# Projection with a (diagonally) modified metric

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

$
%%% NOTATIONS
% sets
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\PPP{\mathbb{P}}
\def\EE{\mathbb{E}}
\def\SS{\mathbb{S}}
\def\SSS{{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}}}
\def\uno{\mathbb{1}}
\def\AA{\mathcal{A}}
\def\BB{\mathcal{B}}
\def\CC{\mathcal{C}}
\def\DD{\mathcal{D}}
\def\FF{\mathcal{F}}
\def\II{\mathcal{I}}
\def\LL{\mathcal{L}}
\def\NN{\mathcal{N}}
\def\PP{\mathcal{P}}
\def\RR{\mathcal{R}}
\def\UU{\mathcal{U}}
\def\HH{\mathcal{H}}
\def\MM{\mathcal{M}}
\def\TT{\mathcal{T}}
\def\XX{\mathcal{X}}
\def\YY{\mathcal{Y}}
% operators
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minn}{min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\maxx}{max}
\def\proj{\text{proj}}
$

Let $y^1\in\R^n, \; y_2\in\R^m$ be fixed. Is this calculation right?

\begin{align*}
\argmin_{\maxx\{|x_1|, 2|x_2|\} = t } |x_1-y_1|^2 + |x_2-y_2|^2\\
= A^{-1}\argmin_{\maxx\{|\bar{x_1}|, |\bar{x_2}|\} = t } |\bar{x_1}-y_1|^2 + |\frac{1}{2}\bar{x_2}-y_2|^2
\end{align*}
where $A=$diag$(1,2)$ is a diagonal $2\times2$ matrix.

We now find the solutions of the last argmin by projecting the solutions of the unconstrained minimization problem on the constraint, which I call "ball of radius $t$ in norm $\infty,2$". Then I rechange variables multiplying by $A^{-1}$. I will also write $X$ for the matrix with rows $x_1$ and $x_2$, and similarly for $\bar{X}$ and $Y$:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\bar{x_1}^** = y_1
\\
\bar{x_2}^** = 2y_2
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow\;\;
\bar{X}* = \proj_{B^{\infty2}(t)}(AY)
\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;
X^* = A^{-1}\bar{X}^* = A^{-1}\proj_{B^{\infty,2}(t)}(AY)
\end{align*}

This seems **wrong** to me but I don't spot the mistake.

EDIT: the title comes from the fact that I got to write the problem as

$ A^{-1}\argmin_{||\bar{X}||_{\infty2}=t} ||A^{-1}(\bar{X}-AY)||_{F}^2 $

($||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm and $||\bar{X}||_{\infty,2}$ is the norm that takes the max of the euclidean norms of rows of $\bar{X}$, $\bar{X}$ being the matrix made by $x_1,x_2$ as rows), so this seems like a projection with a metric modified by the matrix $A^{-1}$.